# Is an AES-256 encryption-decryption a heavy job?

Tags: node.js, security, aes

We have a specific scenario, where our client (our website) holds an encrypted piece of string (consider it to be an encrypted token). When our client makes a request to the server, it shares the encrypted token in the request. (The servers are also handled by us). The server then decrypts the token and then proceeds the action to perform with the token.

Is it a good practice to decrypt the token everytime a request is made? or will this decryption become a heavy job on the server side? Considering it is being done on every request and the requests by the client are also frequent.

Details : We're using Node on the server end and we'll be using AES-256 encryption/decryption.

Comment: Most modern CPUs have built-in [AES commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) that work very efficient and can encrypt/decrypt several hundred MB/sec. Just make sure your server-software uses those commands (e.g. develop a small benchmark and see how fast it is and how much CPU usage it causes).

Comment: Hey @Robert , Thanks! I'll test it with a benchmark first :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you may explain what's the function of the token. Use as a credential or just transit information, if you use it as a credential, you may use a hash algorithm(don't forget to add salt), but if you just want to transit some information, then you use this symmetric encryption algorithm， that's ok, AES is faster than DES.

Comment: Hi @TIAOWANG , Thanks for your response. So, It's actually an authentication token that we wanted to secure. But we cannot Hash it as we'll need the original value of the tokens to make the calls. We'll go with AES for now. Thanks for your help :)